# Why does a conjugated complex term in a sum extend to the whole sum being conjugated

Tags: calculus, complex-numbers

I ask in reference to the following:

If we take a general polynomial $P(\alpha)$ with real coefficients:

$P(\overline\alpha) = \sum_{k=0}^{2n+1} a_k \overline\alpha^k = \sum_{k=0}^{2n+1} \overline{a_k} \overline{\alpha^k} = \sum_{k=0}^{2n+1} \overline{a_k \alpha^k} = \overline{\sum_{k=0}^{2n+1} a_k \alpha^k} = \overline{P(\alpha)}$

Could anyone explain these steps to me as I don't understand how we can work through these equivalences, or give me a hint as to what property allows them to be as they are. 
Thank you!

Comment: Which equality is unclear to you?

Comment: You don't mention the context, but most probably $P$ is a polynomial with *real* coefficients.

Comment: Yes sorry I forgot to state that the coefficients are real, and it was the second one in particular, but by extension the ones following it also.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, I assume that $P$ is a polynomial with **real** coefficients, since, if $P(z)=i\cdot z$, then $P(\overline z) = i\overline z \neq -i\overline z = \overline{P(z)}$.

---

The entire proof uses only three facts:

1. For any two complex numbers $z,w$, $\overline{z+w} = \overline z + \overline w$
2. For any two complex numbers $z,w$, $\overline{z\cdot w} = \overline z \cdot \overline w$
3. For any **real** number $a$, $\overline a=a$.

From the first fact, you can easily see that $$\overline{\sum_{i=1}^n z_i} = \sum_{i=1}^n\overline{z_i}$$
and from the second, that $$\overline{\alpha^k}=\overline\alpha^k$$

Answer (score 1):

The first equality looks like a definition
The second is false in general, but I'm guessing that $P$ is assumed to have real coefficients.  In that case $a_k = \overline{a_k}$ for all $k$. 
The third equality is true because taking conjugates distributes across multiplication, ie. $\overline{ab} = \overline{a}\overline{b}$.
The fourth equality is true because $\overline{a+b} = \overline{a}+\overline{b}$
The fifth equality is again the definition.

Answer (score 0):

**Hint**

$$\overline{z_1+z_2}=\overline{z_1}+\overline{z_2}$$

$$\overline{z_1\cdot z_2}=\overline{z_1}\cdot \overline{z_2}$$

and if $\alpha$ is a real number then

$$\overline{\alpha}=\alpha$$